# How to pass a "Datetime" datatype to SQL with Entity framework (not with strings)?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework-6

I've been looking for a solution to this for hours. The problem I have having is that I have an SQL table which is storing dates as datetime DATATYPES, but when I try to pass a DateTime field to this table with Entity framework It's of datetime2 DATATYPE. All the solutions I found is using strings to format the date but this isn't working for me since I am using Entity Framework, and Entity Framework is expecting a DateTime type variable to be passed to the model and NOT a string.

```
result.SurveyDate = Convert.ToDateTime(CurrentSurveryDateValue);
```

I can't do something like the above because this is sending a datatime2 DATATYPE to the my model result. Which throws this error...

The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Now I can't pass a string formatted to be of datetime format either because it throws a compile time error stating I can only pass DateTime types and not string...

How can i resolve this without changing the date datatype within my SQL table?

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `CurrentSurveryDateValue`? `Convert.ToDateTime(CurrentSurveryDateValue)`?

Comment: What is an example value that is causing an out-of-range error?

Comment: @mjwills The exact value im passing to CurrentSurveryDateValue is 13/10/2017  00:00:00

Comment: @MarcGravell example value is 13/10/2017  00:00:00 which im using for all the dates.